# membership profile properties

Tags: .net, asp.net-membership, profiling, asp.net-profiles

I have a bunch of site's that use the .net membership profile.

Some of the sites have 1000+ users with profiles.

Is it safe to add *new* profile elements?

Like if I want to add: twitter account as a profile element.
**Will this have any conflicts with existing profiles?**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164644.aspx

from my web.config:

```
 <profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="QuickStartProfileSqlProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="QuickStartProfileSqlProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="SimpleTickConnection" applicationName="TheaterSales" />
  </providers>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in one of your staging environments, and roll back if it Fs up-- always an answer

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, it should be safe to add new properties to a profile, although it highly depends on the profile provider you use and how it stores the properties. In the case of the `SqlProfileProvider`, you're safe because of the way the database is structured; other providers maybe not -- you have to look at how the data is stored and how the provider uses it before you can answer that question.

Comment: I'm using: System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider
So I believe based on what you suggest I'm safe. thanks, I'll test it now.